# insert utf-8 string in db

Tags: java, sql

```
String xmlSt = '&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;form&gt;&lt;control&gt;&lt;type&gt;SINGLE&lt;/type&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;column&gt;&lt;level&gt;1&lt;/maxoccurs&gt;&lt;minlength&gt;1&lt;/minlength&gt;&lt;maxlength&gt;250&lt;/maxlength&gt';

String query = "insert into daily_diary(xml_val) values('"+ xmlSt + "'");
int result = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

but it throws like following:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
11:45:04,175 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] The value is not set for the parameter number 1.
```

It throws error when we i pass lengthy string value else it is inserted successfully.
Need a solution to insert lengthy `utf-8` string in db.

Comment: increase the length of column to max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are simply trying to insert a String that is longer than the column's length allows.  Increase the column length if you can.  If you can't, you may need to switch to a different column type.

(This doesn't seem to be UTF-8 related, though if you did have a String in which characters encoded to multiple bytes, you might find that there were more "characters" (actually bytes) stored in the database column than there were characters in the original String.)

---

I should note a couple of other things ... that may be relevant to your problem.

1. Your code sample is not valid Java.  The "string" literal uses single quotes ... and the compiler will reject that.
2. If the actual String contains single quote characters or (potentially) other stuff, the query that you are generating by string bashing could be syntactically invalid SQL.  (Or worse still, it could be valid, but mean something completely unexpected.  Think SQL injection!!!).  You would be advised to use a PreparedStatement with a '?' placeholder in the query, and then add the string as a query parameter.  That will take care of any SQL escaping for you (and protect against SQL injection ... ).
3. You don't need to use HTML / XML entities in a string stored in an SQL database ... unless the application design specifically calls for this.

Comment: Hi, i used PreparedStatement with a '?' placeholder in the query. its successfully inserted. thank u.